# how to change the icon of a button when its clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using this code to switch the icon of a button when it's clicked, the problem is neither the icon is showing nor changing.

```dart
LibraTextField(
    labelText: "Old Password",
    leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
    trailingIcon: AssetsConstants.icUnSee,
    obscureText: _obscureText,
    onTap: iconStatus,),

LibraTextField(
    labelText: "New Password",
    leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
    trailingIcon: AssetsConstants.icUnSee,
    obscureText: _obscureText,
    onTap: iconStatus,),

LibraTextField(
    labelText: "Confirm New Password",
    leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
    trailingIcon: AssetsConstants.icUnSee,
    obscureText: _obscureText,
    onTap: iconStatus,),
```

Declaration of the variables

```dart
bool _obscureText = true;
bool _iconState = true;
var _trailingIcon;

void iconStatus() {
setState(() {
    _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    _iconState = !_iconState;
    if (_iconState = true) {
        _trailingIcon = AssetsConstants.icUnSee;
    }
    if (_iconState = false) {
        _trailingIcon = AssetsConstants.icSee;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't choose the icon on the setState, it is better to do rendering stuff in the build method.  Also, can you elaborate more on your question? The code you posted doesn't show much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void iconStatus() {
    _iconState = !_iconState;
    setState(() {
        _obscureText = !_obscureText;
        _trailingIcon = _iconState ? AssetsConstants.icUnSee : AssetsConstants.icSee;
    });
}
```

If `_obscureText` is work, the icon should work also, otherwise share the part of your code where you are using these booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not store the icon on the state, and choose it in the build method, since it is part of rendering and not actually state.

Looking at your code what is wrong is that you are not using the icon you store on state in `trailingIcon`, you left a constant value.

I made a example of how it could work:

```dart
class SomeForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeFormState createState() => _SomeFormState();
}

class _SomeFormState extends State<SomeForm> {
  var _obscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final icon = _obscureText ? AssetsConstants.icUnSee : AssetsConstants.icSee;
    return Column(
      children: [
        LibraTextField(
          labelText: "Old Password",
          leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
          trailingIcon: icon,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
          onTap: iconStatus,
        ),
        LibraTextField(
          labelText: "New Password",
          leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
          trailingIcon: icon,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
          onTap: iconStatus,
        ),
        LibraTextField(
          labelText: "Confirm New Password",
          leadingIcon: AssetsConstants.icLock,
          trailingIcon: icon,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
          onTap: iconStatus,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```